# showing encoded emoji in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, apache-commons-lang3

I am performing a loop on angular2 with dynamic emoji values encoded with org.apache.commons:commons-lang3 library in android like `\uD83D\uDEB5\uD83D\uDEB5\uD83D\uDEB5`. I need to decode them in angular2 frontend. In itemsArr[index]['Posted Content'] = item[0]['document']['post_content']; I get the encoded content from backend. And 
     this is how I am trying to show them

Code as follows

```
    ngOnInit() {
    this.loading = true;
    var itemsArr = [];

    var reporterPromiseArr = [];
    var postPromiseArr = [];
    var posts = this._cb.getRelationalDataFromTable('reportPost').then(res => {
      res.forEach(item => {
        itemsArr.push({ 'Reported On': item.document.createdAt, 'Posted By': '', 'Posted On': '', 'postId': item.document.post_id });
        postPromiseArr.push(this._cb.getRelationalDataFromTableNew('userActivityStream', [{ key: '_id', value: item.document.post_id }], ['product_id', 'user_id']));
        reporterPromiseArr.push(this._cb.getRelationalDataFromTable('registration', [{ key: '_id', value: item.document.user_id }]));
      });

      return Promise.all(postPromiseArr);
    }).then(res => {
      res.forEach((item, index) => {

        itemsArr[index]['Posted By'] = (item[0]['document']['user_id'] !== null) ? item[0]['document']['user_id']['document']['user_name'] : '';
        itemsArr[index]['Posted On'] = item[0]['document']['createdAt'];
        itemsArr[index]['Posted Type'] = item[0]['document']['type'];
        itemsArr[index]['Total Likes'] = item[0]['document']['total_like'];
        itemsArr[index]['Posted Content'] = item[0]['document']['post_content'];

        itemsArr[index]['Image'] = decodeURI(item[0]['document']['image']);

      });

      //console.log(reporterPromiseArr);
      return Promise.all(reporterPromiseArr);
    }).then(res => {
      res.forEach((item, index) => {
        itemsArr[index]['Reported By'] = item[0]['document']['user_name'];
      });

      this.listingArr = itemsArr;
      this.loading = false;

    }).catch(err => {
      this.loading = false;
      console.log(err)
    });
    console.log(itemsArr);
    //return Promise.all(reporterPromiseArr);


  }

   html as follows where i tried to show them in innerHTML but not working

<form class="tr" #requestData="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(requestData)" *ngFor="let item of listingArr; let i = index">
                                            <div class="td">{{i + 1}}</div>
                                            <div class="td">{{ item['Reported By'] }}</div>
                                            <div class="td">{{item['Reported On'] | date: yMMMdjms }}</div>
                                            <div class="td">{{ item['Posted By'] }}</div>
                                            <div class="td">{{ item['Posted On'] | date: yMMMdjms }}</div>
                                            <div class="td">{{ (item['Total Likes'] == null)?0:item['Total Likes'] }}</div>
                                            <div class="td">{{ item['Posted Type'] }}</div>
                                            <div [innerHTML]="item['Posted Content']"></div>


                                            </div>
                                        </form>
```

Comment: Can you provide your code, please?

Comment: Maybe the issue is not with decodeURIComponent but with something else... Hard to tell without seeing the actual code.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. Original code is in angular2. I edited my post with it. As you see on itemsArr[index]['Posted Content'] = this.doSomething(item[0]['document']['post_content']); line I call dosomething function

Comment: What do you mean "it's not decoding"? Are you sure that your `doSomething` function is being called with what you think it's being called with?

Comment: well it would never work with a timeout.... and the only way that would not work is if str is not what you think it is.... and why would you need to fo unicode escape sequences with decode?

Comment: `decodeURIComponent('\uD83D\uDEB5\uD83D\uDEB5\uD83D\uDEB5') === '\uD83D\uDEB5\uD83D\uDEB5\uD83D\uDEB5'` — `decodeURIComponent` doesn't seem to have anything to do with this.

Comment: yes doSomething is calling successfully. I also tried typeof str which returns string type.

Comment: if you hit decodeURIComponent('\uD83D\uDEB5\uD83D\uDEB5\uD83D\uDEB5') this in console it returns some emoji ""

Comment: `decodeURIComponent` is for percent encoded values. What you have are JavaScript escape sequences.

Comment: um, you can just type in `'\uD83D\uDEB5\uD83D\uDEB5\uD83D\uDEB5'` in the console and it will do it also....

Comment: `decodeURIComponent("foo%3Dbar%20world")` is what URL encoding looks like

Comment: upss you are right @epascarello. I just saw that.These strings are actually encoded with apache lang3 library and I am trying to decode them. Any idea how that should go?

Comment: What do you mean decode them? Is the issue they do not display on the screen when you output it?

Comment: No. They just look like the string is. encoded with org.apache.commons:commons-lang3 in java. trying to decode them

Comment: decode them to do what? What is the goal?

Comment: Just want to show them as emojis on my page

Answer (score 0):

If you need them to be displayed properly on the page, you need to bind them with innerHTML in Angular2

```
<div [innerHTML]="the.path.to.property"></div>
```

Comment: I try with this <div class="td" [innerHTML]="item['Posted Content']"> but sorry nothing happens.